# Simple Syntax Error - CASE WHEN DISTINCT(Column)

Tags: sql-server

Trying to do a case on a distinct value and it isn't going well:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN DISTINCT(Response_Master_Incident.Battalion) = '' THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE DISTINCT(Response_Master_Incident.Battalion) END AS 'Zone'
...
```

and I get the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DISTINCT'."

Comment: DISTINCT does not work at that level. You are not guaranteed to get one row back, so CASE won't be able to evaluate a response. Remove DISTINCT from the CASE statement and move it to the SELECT. That will have a better chance of working.

Comment: @Randolph - What would that syntax look like?  Go ahead and add it as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer looks like this.  Thanks Randolph!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN Response_Master_Incident.Battalion = '' THEN 'Unknown'
    ELSE Response_Master_Incident.Battalion END AS 'Zone'
```

Comment: Is that really the working solution? So if there are 5 rows with an empty string you want the result to look like there is only one? What does the rest of the column list look like? Are you sure you need DISTINCT at all?

Comment: I removed the parentheses from the code. **`DISTINCT` is not a function.** It modifies the `SELECT` clause (you can chosse between DISTINCT and ALL which is the default, so it is rarely added)